# Open source data of the world map that includes longitude and latitude information along with land and sea indicator

Tags: python, plot, gps, openstreetmap, world-map

I've came across OpenStreetMap and it's too large with unnecessary data for my use case.
What I'm searching for is an exact replica of the world map tagged with longitude and latitude information along with an indicator showing whether it's a land or sea, with clear contours of land. I need to be able to draw objects on it and plot it using scripting language like Python. Longitude and latitude information are required for objects I'm plotting and clear contours of land to verify that my plot overlayed above my region of interest.

https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities provides coordinates of countries and its cities but it'd be better to know how large each country is, hence the requirement of land contours. Any other representation of data is acceptable as long as it is able to indicate that there's land.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to have a look at the NaturalEarth datasets...
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

They provide land and ocean shapefiles (and much more) which should fit your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting NaturalEarth datasets. I've been experimenting with OpenStreetMap + Contextly + GeoPandas. OpenStreetMap is pretty big and requires some time to work on. Is there any reason to pick NaturalEarth over OpenStreetMap? Is size the only factor here?

Comment: well, they are 2 completely different things... from your question I thought you're looking for simple shapefiles of general map features (e.g. land/ocean boundaries, labels etc.) which is exactly what naturalearth provides... (the land-shape for example is just 3 mb https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/)  if however you're searching for a detailed map with small-scale features (e.g. buildings etc.) then naturalearth will not help...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A simple shapefile of general map features is indeed what I need for simple plotting of map as well. Seem that I would need both solutions, a lightweight map with general features like NerualEarth dataset for fast rendering and a detailed map like OSM for in-depth analysis.

Comment: yep... that's usually the case :-)  If you search for a python library that helps you with that have a look at [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) ! (I'm the dev :-D )   it supports both OSM (web-tiles) and NaturalEarth features out of the box

Comment: Thanks for introducing EOmaps. That's basically what I need!